Practical example geometry optimization
It is common in electronic structure calculations to perform geometry optimization, which is usually posed as a (numerical) optimization problem. The atom positions are updated using, e.g., gradient descent (GD), conjugate gradient (CG), Newton-Raphson (NR), damped molecular dynamics (MD), and quasi-Newton schemes.
Multiple resources on how these optimization algorithms work are available online. However, I haven't found anything that directly applies such an algorithm to a geometry optimization problem. I want to have an example with matrixes where all the essential optimization steps can be performed by hand. So the electronic steps are left out and performed by an HF, DFT or MD step but the optimization step is illustrated by hand.
As an example, take a simple molecule like $\ce{H2O}$
Given the set of atoms with corresponding forces, how are the atoms' positions updated?
